# How to construct a sgRNA library with multiple samples?

Tags: rna, rna-sequencing

I was wondering if anyone has already experience with constructing sgRNA libraries. We are interested in doing a knock-out experiment (loss-of-function) with 5 different conditions.
I have found this protocol from [Joung et al.](https://www.nature.com/articles/nprot.2017.016/)

In the protocol they have 10 different Fwd primer with no unique barcodes, only the eight Rev primers contains unique barcodes for different samples in KO.
Do I understand it correctly, that I can pool together only eight samples in one sequencing run with this protocol?

I would like to better understand the protocol of constructing an ngs library for sgRNA samples. If someone can point me to the right link/page?

Are there more complex library preparation kits out there which can deal with more samples?

Comment: Hi @AssaYeroslaviz, the question you are asking is wet-lab question on CRISPR rather than a bioinformatics question. You could consider posting on Biology SE if this is the consensus here. The design of a CRISPR construct is a Bioinfo SE question, rather than wet-lab protocols in my opinion